# reflection to list return types, parameters in C# application from specific namespace

Tags: c#, api, reflection, assemblies

I've been working on an API that encapsulates another, trickier-to-use API.  The goal is for my API to not require the user to touch any of the old API by 1) not requiring any parameters of classes in the old API and 2) not returning any instances of classes in the old API.  Is there a program, perhaps a Visual Studio plugin, that can analyze my C# solution and give me a list of all the return types from publicly accessible methods in publicly accessible classes, as well as all the parameter types in such methods?  Otherwise it seems like I'll have to manually go through all my classes and see if any of the old API is exposed to the user.

**Edit:** Since I've been using MSTest for unit testing my API anyway, I added another unit test to use reflection and Fail if any parts of the old API are exposed.  However, I'm stuck with a reflection problem.  I have `using OldAPI` in the unit test class and then I use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(
    assembly => assembly.GetTypes()
)
```

to get a list of the types in all the assemblies currently loaded.  I then iterate over those in hopes of paring down the list of types to only those in the namespace `OldAPI`.  The problem is that the namespace `OldAPI` does not show up.  I see namespaces like Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools, System.Reflection, and others that are included via `using` statements in the test class, but no "OldAPI".  Could this be because of COM stuff with the old API, so `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` doesn't include the assembly even though it's included via a `using` statement in the class?

**Solution:**  I got the necessary assembly by arbitrarily choosing one class I know is in `OldAPI` and doing the following, thanks to [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)' comment:

```
Func<Type, bool> isBad = t => t.Assembly == typeof(OldAPI.SomeClass).Assembly;
```

Here's a snippet of my unit test for checking if any of my API's classes use any of `OldAPI`'s classes, thanks to [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)' answer:

```
MethodInfo[] badMethods = methods.Where(
    m => (
             isBad(m.ReturnType) ||
             m.GetParameters().Any(p => isBad(p.ParameterType))
         ) && !isBad(m.DeclaringType)
).ToArray();
string[] badMethodNames = badMethods.Select(
    m => m.DeclaringType.Name + "." + m.Name
).Distinct().ToArray();
Assert.AreEqual(0, badMethodNames.Length, "Some methods in " +
    monitoredNamespaces + " projects expose OldAPI: " +
    string.Join(", ", badMethodNames));
```

Comment: You're confusing assemblies with namespaces.  You can the the old API's assembly by writing `typeof(OldType).Assembly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ, like this:

```
Func<Type, bool> isBad = t => t.Assembly == badAssembly;

var types = yourAssembly.GetTypes();
var methods = types.SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods()).ToArray();

var badMethods = methods.Where(m => isBad(m.ReturnType) 
    || m.GetParameters().Any(p => isBad(p.ParameterType);

var properties = types.SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()).ToArray();
var badProperties = properties.Where(p => isBad(p.PropertyType));
```

This would be easiest to do in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).

Note that this doesn't traverse generic types, so it'll ignore a `List<BadType>`.
You should probably make `isBad` recursive.  (In which case you should turn it into a regular function)

Comment: You have a couple of misplaced parentheses:  one extra at the end of `var methods` and one missing at the end of `var badMethods`.

Comment: I altered the `badMethods` parameter to `Where` to include `&& !isBad(m.DeclaringType)`, otherwise I see all the classes in the bad API being listed because of course they use other classes in the bad API.  I want only my own classes that use the bad API to be listed.

Comment: I also put `ToArray()` on the end of `var badMethods` and `var badProperties` because `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an existing tool for this, but that doesn't mean you have to do it manually -- you can very easily write your own tool to do this using Reflection.  Basically you'll just need to iterate over Assembly.GetExportedTypes(); for each type, call Type.GetMethods() and Type.GetProperties() and iterate over the results; and dumping the return and parameter types for each method or property that is public.

Note that such a handwritten tool would need to run over your compiled assembly, not your C# source code.  You can do something similar to source code, but it depends on the Visual Studio code model which is rather harder to use and probably not worth the effort for a one-off like this!

Comment: You may have given me an idea for an open source project to write in my free time.  :)